# Bash doesn't quit on syntax error

Tags: bash, debugging

I have a bash code in which I have made a function which is called in the program. I forgot to put a `quotation mark` in one of the statement because of which the script threw a syntax error.Following is the code :

```
#function
write_errors()
{
    #writes RIGHT TRUNCATION errors in bcp import
    temp_file=$1
    error_file=$2
    stepName=$3
    error_count=`fgrep -c "right truncation" ${error_file} "` #here is the extra quotation mark
    ...
}

#start of script
date
...
write_errors  #syntax error happens here
...
date #these lines are executed
rm -f ${temp}
rm -f ${error_file}
...
#end of script
```

My question is after the syntax error in `write_errors`, why does bash executes the line after the syntax error happened ? Why doesn't it quit at the syntax error like other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `bash` doesn't exit on error.

You can request that behaviour by adding the following line at the beginning of your script:

```
set -o errexit
```

Note that there's a shorthand for it:

```
set -e
```

[This article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) has a few pointers as to why this isn't the default behaviour in bash.

---

If you want to write robust bash scripts, you might also want to look at another flag, `nounset`, which errors out on undefined variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but why is it made by default ? What is the need of such a behavior where the program doesn't quit on `syntax error` ?

Comment: @snyder This page should have some details: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 There are caveats to having `set -e` by default, because `bash` treats all errors (syntax errors, nonzero output codes) equivalently.

Comment: Great, that is what I was looking for :). Can you add this link in your answer.